# target separate fields of my taxonomy term in my view using twig

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a view displaying taxonomy terms as fields by making use of a responsive grid. I have a twig file based on views-view-grid-responsive.html.twig.

in this twig file there is a loop {% for item in items %}  and than in there  {{- item.content -}} which is basically displaying the whole taxonomy term.  in my case simply the name and an image.

I am trying to find a way to target each field/value separately

It was suggested that:
{{ item.content['#node'].field_name.value }}
would do that, but it doesn't show any content at all.
I also tried
{{ item.content['#taxonomy_term'].field_name.value }}
but also no results so far

hope anyone can help

thanx in advance!